# textmate undefined method '+' for nil nilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: textmate2

Can Someone help me find out why textmate not

working with ^+shift+O to open terminal .

When I do this, tm just popup a window saying

Failure running "Open Terminal".

Open Terminal:2:undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)

Then I Click Edit Command button, goto Open Terminal shell script
And Find out the following code:

require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/escape.rb'

contains the operator +.

I guess that's the problem but don't know how to fix it .

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Ok,then I solve it myself:) refering to this article https://github.com/elia/avian-missing.tmbundle/issues/3

Just install bundle support and bundle development to fix it!